# Custom navigation drawer flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, custom-painter

I am trying to create custom navigation drawer just like bottom navigation but in navigation drawer.I am not able to achieve the view we want.I tried using custom painter but i am not expert in it.Suggest some websites where i can learn custom painter basic to advance level.

[image: Require custom navigation]

[image: My custom painter]

My code :

```
 class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {



    Paint paint0 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
     // ..strokeWidth = 1;


    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(size.width*0.0025000,size.height*0.0042857);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.2481250,size.height*0.0010714,size.width*0.3300000,0);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.3308333,size.height*0.1385714);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.1392500,size.height*0.1384000,size.width*0.1247083,size.height*0.2564000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.1423583,size.height*0.3717143,size.width*0.3328917,size.height*0.3609143);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.3328417,size.height*0.9951571);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.0033333,size.height*0.9957143);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.0031250,size.height*0.7478571,size.width*0.0025000,size.height*0.0042857);
    path0.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path0, paint0);


  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: did you use `shapemaker` for painter?

Comment: Yes. I tried but not able change position of curve dynamically

Comment: Perfect . Thank you @pskink . Created sample project in github. Metioned you help. Please check https://github.com/sivabalan7811/fluttercustomnavigationdrawer

Comment: Nothing. Please share any one need help thank you

Comment: Oh okay thank you

Comment: that duplicate, i just tried in two places thats it. your example is much helpful